# Iterating through Single Entity to HTML Unordered List

Tags: c#, html, model-view-controller, iteration

I am looking for a nudge or maybe a little more than a nudge in the right direction to help me work through this.

I am creating a organistation chart using C#, MVC and CSS unordered list

I have a viewmodel with the follwoing properties

EmployeeName

EmployeeID

EmployeeReporttoID

LevelOF

This data is retrieved from SQL using a similar Sproc as shown here 
[OrgChartHierarchyy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3309405/tough-t-sql-to-display-org-chart-hierarchy-recursion)

An example of the returned data might be

EmployeeName, EmployeeID, EmployeeReporttoID, LevelOF

John, empID1,, 1

Jane, empID2,empID1, 2

Mary, empID3,empID1, 2

Harry, empID4, empID1, 2

Joe, empID7, EmpID2, 3

Arnold, empID8, EmpID2, 3

Gary, empID9, empID7, 4
...

for sure the above could go on and on depeneding on the depth of the employee tree

The question is how I then iterate through the above to turn it into an HTML unordered list where each of the employees have the associated people reporting to them as list Items?

Many thanks for any help 
D

Comment: Please format this question...

Answer (score 0):

loop through the list twice, the first loop will write the un-ordered list, while the second loop will check if the employee in question has people reporting to them. Based on this, it will write it out

```
foreach (var EmployeeDetail in Model)
{
<h3><ul>@EmployeeDetail.EmployeeName</ul></h3> 
<div>
    <ol>    
        @foreach (var ReportingEmployee in Model)
        {
            @if(@EmployeeDetail.EmployeeID==ReportingEmployee.EmployeeReporttoID)
            {
              <li>@EmployeeDetail.EmployeeName</li>
            }


        }
    </ol>
</div>
}
```